# "Make curtain" --Is this a well known usage of this expression?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> "We were busy [working in the kitchen] for pretheater, a mad rush to
> get them in and get them out in time to make curtain."

This quotes is from Anthony Bourdain's book describing that they are busy working for people going to theaters before the show.

My question is: Is "make curtain" a well known, well used expression to say make the show in time, or this is quite casual saying by Anthony? When I googled this expression, I could not find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems likely that it’s something “theater people” say and common folk don’t.

Comment: Also note that the use of “make” is idiomatic for all.  It’s the use of “curtain” as a metonym for showtime that’s theater jargon

Comment: I've just googled "make curtain" and got no hits except for pages on physically fabrication curtains; however "make curtain-up" returned lots of hits. I'd never heard "make curtain" in this context but I have heard "make curtain-up". "Make curtain" mabe an in-group version of "make curtain-up" but it does not seem to be very common..

Comment: "Make curtain" is to be found (provided you disallow drapery with `-curtains`) for example on [Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g186338-i17-k11751806-Is_this_possible_From_Nottingham_play_to_London_play-London_England.html): *I think worse case scenario would be I wouldn't **make curtain** and would have to stand in back until interval.*

Comment: ... some of the search results turn up *make curtain **time***.

Comment: @Jim, I'd grant that only on condition that the category "theater people" include theater-goers. And once we add them to the professional and amateur thespians and crew, I think we shall find such persons plenty "common" (not in the derogatory classist sense).

Comment: @BrianDonovan - Granted [this](https://www.arts.gov/sites/default/files/American-Participation-in-Theater.pdf) is reporting on 1992 levels (it was the first thing I found) but this says only 13% of the US adult population had reported seeing a live stage production.  (~25m out of 185m adults).  So, is that “common” or uncommon?

Comment: It's very common for waiters at restaurants in the Broadway district to ask customers who walk in 60-90 minutes before showtimes whether they have theater tickets: *Do you have a curtain to make?* Soup? Coming right up. Rack of lamb? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

In legitimate theater and shows with the same rules *Curtain* is the clock time that the entire caste and crew must be on site. This is usually no less that an hour before the curtain actually *Goes Up* and often much more. The operative question backstage during the days before the show is *When's Curtain?*, that is, when do I need to be here.

Your story may involve people who are only going to see the show but the phrase *Make Curtain* refers to the backstage drop dead time. Since Anthony Bourdain was very familiar with theater jargon it is likely that they had the phrase in mind even if it was for a simpler use.

Comment: This is really interesting and makes sense if the narrator in the extract is either a catering worker within the theatre or in a restaurant or lodging house catering to actors and other theatrical people. They would have been very conscious of the need for the diners to "make curtain". There is a similarity with the need for deep miners to get to the pithead early enough to get ready for the time when the cage drops at the start of the shift.

Comment: thanks for the insights, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The play begins when the curtain goes up. Traditional theaters have curtains that cover the stage when the play is not in progress, or between scenes when the set is being changed.

The curtain goes down when the play is over, but opens again for curtain calls, when the cast appears to be applauded by the audience.

So curtain time is when the play begins.

> cur·tain time
> noun
> the beginning of a stage performance.
> "curtain time is at 8 p.m."

Oxford Dictionaries